# Proving that $n^2 + n$ is even for any integer $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This type of question often shows up in introductory abstract math courses, computer science discrete math, or an introduction to logic course.

**Show that $n^2 + n$ is even for any integer n.**

Comment: $\textbf{Shortest argument is}$: if consider any two consecutive number one of them must be even so product will be even.

Comment: That's exactly my answer, @SiddhantTrivedi...but indeed with less words.

Answer (score 8):

$n^2+n=n(n+1)$ and either $n$ is even or $n+1$ is even. In any case, their product is even.

Comment: I like how long this took compare to the suppose and expand method

Answer (score 6):

$$n^2+n=n(n+1)$$

So the above is the product of two consecutive integers and then one of them exactly **must** be even and thus so is the product.

Answer (score 5):

**Before beginning, you should understand the following:**

```
even * even = even
even + even = even
odd  + odd  = even
odd  * odd  = odd
```

**First, suppose $n$ is odd:**

`n = 2k + 1` 
is the formula of an odd number $n$ (this means $2k+1$ always produces an odd number $n$, try it by plugging in any integer for $k$).

Let's use this fact of `n = 2k + 1` with the expression we are trying to prove is always even; remember the original expression? It is: $$n^2 + n$$ is always even.

**Second, plug in for $n$:**

Using our odd number formula that we know `n = 2k + 1` 
and our original expression $n^2 + n$, plug in

$n^2 + n = (2k+1)^2 + (2k+1)$

Using the **right-hand side**:

**Expand** it by "foiling":
$(2k+1)^2 + (2k+1)$

$(4k^2 + 4k + 1) + (2k + 1)$

**Simplified**: $4k^2 + 6k + 2$

Bring back the left-hand side and put it all together:
$n^2 + n = 4k^2 + 6k +2$

Analyzing the right-hand side you can see that no matter what $k$ is, it is multiplied by 4, which makes it always even (this applies to both the $k$'s. Same goes for the $6k$ because 6 is even. And as it always has been: 2 will always be an even number.

### Now you need to suppose $n$ is even, instead of odd

Do the same steps you did above but instead of `n = 2k + 1` for all odd numbers, you need to know that `n = 2k` for all **even** numbers.

Take your original expression that you're trying to prove is always even: $n^2 + n$ **and** your newly discovered even number formula $n = 2k$ ***then*** plug in just like you did above.

Comment: Ah, but if this is asked in a course on logic, don't you need to prove the four statements at the beginning of your answer? Or are they to be taken as axiomatic?

Comment: I just put that there to give a little background, some people don't think about numbers like that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different take. Use Gauss's trick:

$S = 1 + 2 + \cdots + n$

$S = n +(n-1) + \cdots + 1$

$2S = (n+1) + (n+1) + \cdots + (n+1) = n(n+1)$

Thus, $n(n+1)=2S$ is even.